# How to clear a class after it is no longer being by any thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Say i have a Map class, which has some data used for ready only, and there are multiple workers (threads) using this class at the same time.

If i wanted to clear that map instance (erase it's data) when it is no longer being used by any worker, how would i do that efficiently in a thread safe way?

Something like this:

```
public class Map
{
    public static Map activeMap;
    public int used;

    public void BeginWork()
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref used);
    }

    public void EndWork()
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref used);

        if(this != activeMap && used == 0)
        {
            Erase();
        }
    }

    // This method is only called on the main thread.
    public static void ChangeActiveMap(Map newActiveMap)
    {
        Map previousMap = activeMap;
        activeMap = newActiveMap;
        if (previousMap.used == 0) 
        {
            previousMap.Erase();
        }
    }

    private void Erase()
    {
        // Erase Map data here.
        // Put Map into a pool for later use and prevent it from going to GC.
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    private Map map;

    public void BeginWork()
    {
        Map.activeMap.BeginWork();
        map = Map.activeMap;

        //  Do work here with map data.

        map.EndWork();
        map = null;
    }
}
```

If the map gets erased while a worker is still using it, the worker will work on blank map data, which will lead to error. I get the feeling that the code above will not work properly. It would really be a plus doing this without using locks.

EDIT : Map data is too expensive to go into GC, the idea with the Clear method is to recycle it and put it into a pool for later use without ever going into GC.

Maybe the code works assuming that it will only get cleared if it is no longer the activeMap, because new workers will only start a new work with the activeMap ?

EDIT: Added the ChangeActiveMap method to the code. I think is method is also a problem for multithreading.

Comment: Thanks for c# and java designers.. You don't need to do anything.... GC will handle it for you...

Comment: I guess i should have mentioned it. The Map data is expensive to go through GC, so once the map is no longer used, it goes into a pool for recycling and it never gets collected by GC.

Comment: `Map data is too expensive to go into GC,` No other way to `recycle` it..... (Maybe you can want to write your own memory manager, by allocating a big mem beforehand and writing all other depending methods by yourself...)

Comment: @Eser You misunderstand. By pooling items, they never get collected. It's a technique to prevent memory-thrashing and excessive GC collections.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it looks like `BeginWork` and `EndWork` might be replaced by having `BeginWork` return an `IDisposable` that calls `EndWork` when disposed. That way, you can scope everything nicely in a `using(map.BeginWork()){}` without worrying about the responsibility of calling `EndWork` when finished.